# Storing useful data from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm very new to c# and trying to muddle my way around things. I'm used to coding on an iSeries (RPG) so c# is a very different concept to me.

I have a stored procedure which returns a row (or rows) of data depending on the matching rows.

Imagine my table *users* holds the following columns:

```
UserId, CompanyId, FirstName, LastName, CompanyAdmin, AccountStatus, UserName.
```

I have a stored procedure which returns all of these columns where there is a matching Company ID (ie.. `Select * from users where CompanyId = 1`).

I have created a class with matching fields as above and the appropriate get/set methods (ie. `public int UserId {get; set;}` etc).

I've used a `SqlDataReader` and am attempting to load each field from my class with data from the reader, but I'm getting an error

> 'reader["UserName"]' threw an exception of type
>
> 'System.InvalidOperationException' object
>
> {System.InvalidOperationException}

What am I missing? Ultimately I would like an object that has all of my fields defined that will match my result set from my SQL Server stored procedure.

My code throwing the error looks like this..

```
    public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("ot_Users");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "dbo.ot_User_GetByUserName";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Environment.UserName);

                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                ot_Users user = new ot_Users();

                while(reader.Read())
                {
                     user.CompanyId = (int) reader["CompanyId"];
                     user.UserId = (int) reader["UserId"];
                     user.FirstName = (String) reader["FirstName"];
                     user.LastName = (String) reader["LastName"];
                     user.CompanyAdmin = (bool) reader["CompanyAdmin"];
                     user.AccountStatus = (int) reader["AccountStatus"];
                     user.UserName = (String) reader["UserName"];
                }

                reader.NextResult();

                CompanyName.Text = user.FirstName.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: firstname, lastName and Username. are they (char) isnt that should be string?

Comment: I've changed them now, but still get the same problem

Comment: try string with lower case 's'.

Comment: Can we see the selected coulumns from your stored procedure? Also always try to minimize posibilities of exception! e.g. try `reader["FirstName"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["FirstName"].ToString() : string.Empty;`

Comment: i was about to write that.. good catch @humpty dumpty

Comment: ok I've changed from "String" to "string" and get a different error now..

I'm getting a nullreference exception on line 

CompanyName.Text = user.FirstName.ToString();

huMpty duMpty - I've tried the line you suggested but my editor doesn't like it (only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement).

Comment: As for my stored procedure (you guys will hate this I'm sure)

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.OTUser
    WHERE CompanyId = @CompanyId;

Comment: Have a debug point on that line and check `?reader["UserName"].GetType()` on immediate window. You will see what type is coming and you need to cast it to the same type and also `user.UserName` should be of that type as well.

Comment: `while(reader.Read())` will read until EOF then after that you are trying to advance to the next record `reader.NextResult();` are you sure this isnt causing a problem? You are also missing braces for the first `using`

Comment: I've commented out the reader.NextResult() and still get the same issue, it looks like my SP is not returning any rows, although I've checked and it certainly should do, let me do some testing on the stored proc and see if that is my culprit.

thanks everyone for your responses so far, much appreciated.

Comment: Just need to check that there are records in the DB that match the username of the user logged into the machine

Comment: Found it! 

My parameter on the SP was defined incorrectly, I'd defined it as varchar and not varchar(50) so I presume this defaulted to 1 character.

I'm still getting errors now my SP is returning data, but this is down to casting problems which I can sort.

Thanks everyone for your tips and also the help in tidying up my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

Please note : that if your sproc returns more than one row it will take the last one only. because you are looping through an object only. if you are expecting more result than you should use List or somekind a collection object.

```
 public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("ot_Users");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                command.CommandText = "dbo.ot_User_GetByUserName";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Environment.UserName);

                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                ot_Users user = new ot_Users();

                while(reader.Read())
                {
                     user.CompanyId = reader["CompanyId"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)reader["CompanyId"] : 0 ;
                     user.UserId = reader["UserId"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)reader["UserId"] : 0 ;
                     user.FirstName = reader["FirstName"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["FirstName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                     user.LastName = reader["LastName"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["LastName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                     user.CompanyAdmin = reader["CompanyAdmin"] != DBNull.Value ? (bool)reader["CompanyAdmin"] : false ;
                     user.AccountStatus = reader["AccountStatus"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)reader["AccountStatus"] : 0 ;
                     user.UserName = reader["UserName"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["UserName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                }

                if (user != null)
                {
                    CompanyName.Text = user.FirstName.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be with casting UserName as a `char`. A `char` represents a single character only, a string represents multiple characters, so you might want to use that one instead!

That or perhaps the `UserName` isn't cased properly?

Comment: Ok - I've changed that and I'm still getting the same error, I've double checked my ot_User.cs and the fields in there are also defined as String (they are now anyway).

Comment: ``char`` is probably wrong but the cast can't be the source of the error he reported because it happens after the reader fetches the data.

Comment: Could you post the actual schema of your data? What DB/Server are you using?